# Why does number in Array work, but not String in Array?

Tags: javascript

```
1 in [1, 2] //true
"foo" in ["foo", "bar"] //false
1 in [1] //false - ? what's going on here?
```

Comment: `in` is not `indexOf`, reading the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) might help.

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: I did, actually. And I found `indexOf`. But that still didn't explain why `in` wasn't working. umad that people here actually want to learn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `in` operator does not check if the element is in an array (like Python or JS Array's `indexOf`), it checks if the *object* has a property with the given name.

You want to use `indexOf` here, since that actually checks to see if the value is contained in the array. That will work with numbers and strings, but not always objects (you must provide the exact same object, not equivalent ones).

In example #1, an array with two elements has an element named `1` (the second element in the array). In example #3, an array with one element does not.

Since array elements are numbered, there is no `foo` element in any array.

If you were to use:

```
var data = ["foo", "bar"];
data.foo = "baz";
```

then `"foo" in data` would return true.

Answer (score 2):

`that in foo` tests to see if there is a property **named** that, not if there is a property with a **value** that matches that.

`x = [1, 2]` is the same as `x = []; x[0] = 1; x[1] = 2`. `x[1]` exists so `1 in x`is true.

`x = ["foo", "bar"]` is the same as `x = []; x[0] = "foo"; x[1] = "bar"`. `x[1]` doesn't exist so `1 in x`is false.

You're looking for the `indexOf` method.

```
["foo", "bar"].indexOf("foo") >= 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The `in` operator checks for the existence of a given **key** on your array, which means that:

```
1 in [1, 2] // Checks if arr[1] exists
"foo" in ["foo", "bar"] // Checks if arr['foo'] exists
1 in [1] // Checks again if arr[1] exists
```

Remember that array's keys are by default numeric indexes, so `[1, 2]` and `['foo', 'bar']` contains `0` and `1` keys and `[1]` contains only `0` key.

If you want to check whether an array contains a given **value**, you should propably use the [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method:

```
[1, 2].indexOf(1) !== -1 // true
["foo", "bar"].indexOf("foo") !== -1 // true
[1].indexOf(1) // true
```

You might want to read the [MDN docs about the `in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).

Answer (score 2):

ther is the "for-in" that is used to cycle associative arrays, like this

```
for( i in myArray ) {
  // Do something with myArray[ i ];
}
```

and "in" instruction ("x in y") is true if "y" has an element with KEY x and not VALUE x

If you want to test the existance of a data in an array

```
if( myArray.indexOf( "foo" ) > -1 ) {
  // "foo" is there
}
```

Comment: And as I said in the subsequent row, the simple "in" do not give you the presence of an element in an array, but the presence of a key in an array

Comment: You're right, that's was not correct by my wording, I'll correct